# RestSharp - GET request with "$" response attribute name

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, restsharp

I need to get GET response from REST API. I use RestSharp. The problem is, that one name of the response attribute is "$". This is the response:

```
[
    {
        "CodeId": {
            "$": "00000000"
        },
        "Entity": {
            "LegalName": {
                "@xml:lang": "cs",
                "$": "xxxxx"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

How should I use the RestSharp to get the value of Entity.LegalName.$ ?

Comment: `RestSharp` should giving you response. With that you can convert to object using `Json.Net`. Provide the `JsonProperty` name as '$' in your object.

Comment: @user1672994 can you write me a simple example? I normally use RestSharp with the generic method Execute<SomeResponseTemplate>.

Comment: `$` is not a valid character for an [identifier to start with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/identifier-names). You will need to use the [JsonPropertyNameAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) or if you're using .NET Core 3.0 the [JsonAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonattribute?view=netcore-3.0) unless you're still using newtonsoft.

Comment: You can tell RestSharp to give you an object based on a model that is created based on your JSON string but because you can not create a class that it's property name be "$" then you can get string json response from Restsharp then create `JObject obj = new JObject(jsonString);` (using JSON.net)  and get your value manually by calling `string value = (string)obj["$"]`

Comment: @fredrik Im using .NET Core 3. Can you write me some example?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/

Comment: Check [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VE1W2v) dotnetfiddle which demos using `NewtonSoft.Json` package. You can write accordingly for .Net core3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer thanks by @fredrik.

```
      var client = new RestClient(url);

      var request = new RestRequest(urlRequest, DataFormat.Json);

      var response = client.Get(request);

      Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TestRestResponseTemplate>>(response.Content)[0].Entity.LegalName.Value);
```

TestRestResponseTemplate:

```
  public class TestRestResponseTemplate
  {
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
  }

  public class LegalName
  {
    [JsonPropertyName("@xml:lang")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("$")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
  }

  public class Entity
  {
    public LegalName LegalName { get; set; }
  }
```